# How to read video from Directus in Safari

Tags: html, safari, cross-browser, html5-video, directus

I have an app that fetches medias videos from Directus.These video files are in .webm format.

my video element:

```
<video autoplay muted loop class="viewerVideo">
    <source src="https://directusaddress.com/assets/fileUID" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

this works fine in firefox and chrome.

In safari, the video element is there, but it is empty, no image show up. But, if the same file is stored localy (in the app's folders), the same code will work.  So the problem seems to be related to the fact that the file isn't stored localy.

Any clues?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the Safari developer console?

Comment: Nope, I have no error in the console.  The <video> tag show up in the inspector, but no errors show up in the console.

Comment: i have the same issues, but i'm getting an obscure error: 
`Refused to load media from 'https://path-to-directus.com/assets/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src none". Note that 'media-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`